# Vertically align div with absolute positioning and percentage height

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="logo">
    <div class="navigation-left menu"></div>
</div>

#logo {
    position: relative;
    background: #0099ff url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto 55%;
    height: 18%;
}

.navigation-left {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 3%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
    background-image: url('../img/3lines.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I am trying to vertically centre `.navigation-left` so it sits in the middle of `#logo`. As far as I can see I need to use absolute positioning on `.navigation-left` so that I can use `auto` for the `width` property. This rules out `vertical-align` as that sets the div's `display` to `block`. Any ideas?

Comment: Jsfiddle please because I can't see this working without **some** actual numbers other than percentages. Why do you have background properties on a class with no background except that set in another class?

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle with full urls to the images?

Comment: You're setting `.navigation-left` to 3% of the height of `#logo` which is 18% of what container?  how is the parent container defined? `navigation-left` is empty and set to auto width. Why?

Answer (score 0):

**1]** Set `position:absolute;` `top:50%;`.

**2]** Set `margin-top:-1.5%;` or half of the element's `height`.

Code:

```
.navigation-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-1.5%; /* Should be set to half of the height */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 3%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is to be actual content in the menu div then negative margin would have to be calculated and set manually (or by JS).

Here is a CSS3 solution which is dynamic using`transforms`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UavH4/3/) (fiddle updated re % header but relevant CSS still applies)

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">
    <div class="navigation-left menu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height:100%; /* not required but guessed at based on % height in OP */
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    height: 100px; /* any value */
}

.navigation-left {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0%, -50%);
    height:3%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: blue;

}
```